# Xcode 7.3.1 New Project Screen Fields

Tags: user-interface, xcode7

Recently, when I try to create a new project, the "Choose options for your new project" screen is messed up.  All of the labels are over-writing the text entry fields.

[Image of Xcode Screen](http://perlguy.net/xcode_new_project_error.png)

The link is to an image that shows exactly what is happening.

I am also seeing the same type of anomalies on some of the other templates for creating new files in a project.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I'm having the same exact problem.

Comment: No.  Using Xcode 8.x now and haven't seen the issue.